# Simple index on DATE and TIME columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a CSV containing data that looks like this:

```
<DATE>      <TIME>    <OPEN>  <LOW>  <HIGH>  <CLOSE>  
2001-01-03  00:00:00  0.9507  0.9505  0.9509  0.9506  
....   
2015-05-13  02:00:00  0.9496  0.9495  0.9509  0.9505
```

I want to create an index on <DATE> and <TIME> but retain the two columns as normal columns so I can reference them.

As the data is stored in a CSV I am not sure how I could parse the 2 columns (DATE and TIME) into one before creating the dataframe.

I've had a look at many answers but they seems convoluted for what I am trying to do, and I have became convinced I am missing the simple solution

```
Context around what lead me to this:
```

The proper way I've identified setting a new value (for when I am computing rolling mean values) is:

```
df.set_value('index', 'column', value)
```

Because my index is currently just on date, referencing the index for a particular row (say, the 1st row) means many values are set instead of one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [170]: df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', parse_dates={'TIMESTAMP': ['DATE','TIME']}).set_index('TIMESTAMP')

In [171]: df
Out[171]:
                       OPEN     LOW    HIGH   CLOSE
TIMESTAMP
2001-01-03 00:00:00  0.9507  0.9505  0.9509  0.9506
2001-01-03 01:00:00  0.9507  0.9505  0.9509  0.9506
2001-01-03 02:00:00  0.9507  0.9505  0.9509  0.9506
2001-01-03 03:00:00  0.9507  0.9505  0.9509  0.9506
2001-01-03 04:00:00  0.9507  0.9505  0.9509  0.9506
2001-01-04 00:00:00  0.9507  0.9505  0.9509  0.9506
2001-01-04 01:00:00  0.9507  0.9505  0.9509  0.9506
2001-01-04 02:00:00  0.9507  0.9505  0.9509  0.9506

In [172]: df.index.dtype
Out[172]: dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

**OLD answer:**

you can do it this way:

```
In [155]: df
Out[155]:
   a  b  c
0  0  0  3
1  1  2  0
2  2  2  3
3  1  0  0
4  1  3  2
5  4  0  1
6  2  0  3
7  2  1  2
8  3  3  4
9  0  0  3

In [156]: df.join(df.iloc[:, :2], rsuffix='_idx').set_index((df.iloc[:, :2].columns + '_idx').tolist())
Out[156]:
             a  b  c
a_idx b_idx
0     0      0  0  3
1     2      1  2  0
2     2      2  2  3
1     0      1  0  0
      3      1  3  2
4     0      4  0  1
2     0      2  0  3
      1      2  1  2
3     3      3  3  4
0     0      0  0  3
```

BUT, you don't really need it, because it's redundant - you still have your data in the index and can use it...

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

Comment: Sorry I should be clear, there are multiple rows for each DATE value, i.e. 2015-01-01 00:00 and 2015-01-01 01:00. So if I index of DATE I have multiple rows if I reference a single date. If that makes sense?

Comment: @cardycakes, your goals aren't clear... You can parse DATE and TIME into single TIMESTAMP (dtype: `datetime`) column and set it as an index. Can you explain what do you want to do with your DF?

Comment: That makes sense. But as the data is in a CSV, do you mean I should parse the two columns into one, then set the index after creating the DF?

Comment: Thanks MaxU, that's perfect